# Does JavaFX2 WebView support angularjs?

Tags: java, angularjs, webview, javafx-2

When trying to authenticate users for Spotify the user has to be redirected after logging into the Spotify service. The page to enter the credentials opens in the WebView just fine but the redirect never happens it just sits there on the log in screen. While looking at the web pages source it looked like it uses angularjs but I have never used angularjs and don't know where to start. I couldn't find if there was any support for angular js online.

Comment: Generally it *does* support Angular. I've run from simple to pretty complex Angular applications in WebView. BUT there may be incompatibilities in how Angular is being used in that specific application, or in other libraries/APIs used.